# DateTimePicker changing format based on locale

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, date, datepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

The datepicker included i chrome browser allow the users to select dates. The user will see the date in a format and the input value will be always in the format: "YYYY-MM-DD".

I want the same behavior when using [bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker).

If I specify the format when initializing the plugin like this

```
$('.date-picker').datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
});
```

when I get the input value it's in the same format, 'DD/MM/YYYY'. I want it to be in the standard format which is "YYYY-MM-DD".

Same thing when I specify the locale.

```
$('.date-picker').datetimepicker({
    locale: 'fr'
});
```

Can any one help me?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

When you initialize the bootstrap-datetimepicker plugin you can choose the [format](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#format) you prefer, so you can have:

```
$('.date-picker').datetimepicker({
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
});
```

Then the input value will be in the format 'YYYY-MM-DD'.

If you need to display the date in a given format and then convert it in another one you can use [Moment format function](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/). For example:

```
$('#yourpickerid').datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
});

function getPickerValue(){
    // Get picker date
    var val = $('#yourpickerid').data("DateTimePicker").date();
    // Convert date to given format
    var dateStr = val.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    return dateStr;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, I can not do that. In fact, I'm using MeteorJs  with autoform, a package that handles form validations.

Comment: I can suggest you to edit your question specifying that you are using MeteorJs and autoform. I don't know well enough autoform, but maybe [here](http://autoform.meteor.com/types) you can find useful information.